# Add new field to nested array document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My document structure looks like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "657097f82495a36052e69513"},
    "key": "peril_thresholds",
    "value": {
      "RAIN": [
        {
          "_id": {"$oid": "658194da0000000000e9da57"},
          "quantity": null,
          "meteoEventType": "RAIN",
          "meteoEventLabel": "PRECIPITAZIONE",
          "meteoEventLevel": "NO_DATA",
          "meteoEventLevelLabel": "Nessun dato disponibile"
        },
...
```

I need to insert a new field `basicLabel` into the document with id `658194da0000000000e9da57`

I am trying to update the document exploiting the position inside the nested array without any success though

```
db.config.updateOne({"_id": ObjectId("657097f82495a36052e69513")},
{
    $set: {
        "value.RAIN.0.basicLabel": "Nessun dato disponibile"
    }
}
);
```

Comment: couldnt reproduce https://mongoplayground.net/p/p6kq08c0hwk

Comment: Same. Your update query [is already working](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VASukeyh8VZ). What version of MongoDB are you on?

Comment: @aneroid I'm on Mongo 4.4